# Forwarding refs with memoised map: undefined is not a function (near mapRef.animateToRegion)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ref, react-native-maps

I have the following React Native component, utilising `react-natve-maps` for map displays. I require a `ref` to the map to use its `animateToRegion` function in a separate component, and as I am using React's `memo` to prevent unnecessary re-renders during expensive map draws (eg, heatmaps), I am therefore also using `forwardRef` as functional components cannot have `ref` props.

I've ended up with the following:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
} from 'react-native';
import {
  MapView,
  Marker,
} from 'react-native-maps';

const MemoMap = React.memo(
  React.forwardRef((props, ref) =>(
    <MapView
      ref={ref}
      initialRegion={{
        latitude: 0,
        longitude: 5,
        latitudeDelta: 0.01,
        longitudeDelta: 0.01,
      }}
      style={StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject}>
      <Marker
        coordinate={{
          latitude: 0,
          longitude: 5,
        }} />
    </MapView>
  )
), () => false);

export default function App() {
  const mapRef = React.createRef();

  const snapToMarker = () => {
    mapRef.animateToRegion({
      longitude: 0,
      latitude: 0,
      longitudeDelta: 0.01,
      latitudeDelta: 0.01,
    })
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <MemoMap ref={mapRef} />
      <Button onPress={snapToMarker} />
    </View>
  );
}
```

(I've mocked the `memo` equality function for simplicity)

However, the ref always has `current: null` and not the map reference. Therefore, clicking the button simply throws `undefined` on the `animateToRegion` event call.

What can I do to get the map reference I require?

Comment: I can't test it atm but maybe this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-native-y5t9z) will help you a bit.

Comment: Your example was very helpful, realised I was missing the `.current` part :)